# TypeScript 1.5: Export default implementing an interface

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript 1.5, I have the following interface in `IFoo.ts`:

```
// IFoo.ts
interface IFoo<T> {
    bar(): T;
}
```

And an implementation in `FooString.ts`:

```
// FooString.ts
export default {
    bar: () => 'Hello world'
}
```

How can the module `FooString.ts` declare the object literal it is exporting as an implementation of `IFoo<sring>`? Without a declaration, the implementation of the interface is not checked by the compiler, and losing compile-time checking of the `FooString` module would be problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting in 1.5 will preserve the compile-time checking, so this will work:

```
export default <IFoo<string>> {
    bar: () => 'Hello world'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
export var defaults:IFoo<string> = {
    bar: () => 'Hello world'
}
```

Comment: This is rather sparse. Can you add some text to explain this code / how it solves the OP's problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not the appropriate answer. Exporting a variable named `defaults` does nothing.